# Set Environment Variable for specific application that starts at login

Tags: macos, login-items, environment-variables

I need to set an env var for an app on MacOs.  This is an app that I want to run on startup (currently via Login Items).  I can set the env var as a LaunchAgent plist file with the RunAtLoad key set and it will set the env var correctly but on reboot the app starts before this env var is set.  If I close the app and restart it, it accepts the env variable.

I have also created a .zshenv file and set it there but have the same issue.

How can I set this env var to be effective for the OS or user session before the app is started via login items?